# Handling GPT-2 Tokenization and Encoding in a Text Processing Pipeline

Tags: character-encoding, tokenize, gpt-2

I'm currently working on a text processing pipeline that involves tokenization with GPT-2 and spaCy for French. However, I'm encountering problems related to character encoding and tokenization outputs.
After the gpt2 tokenisation, the words change, for instance **voilà** to **VoilÃł**. And then for the next step, I'll have an issue, as the word can't be found in the text.

I tried *chardet.detect(text.encode())* to change it back to the original word, but it didn't work.
Have you ever face this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].